# finding a date range in an array - Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

the challenge is:  if a Holiday Date ($F) falls in between (A2:B2, A3:B3,etc) I want to copy the the Holiday Name ($G to the associated reason column $D & the Count $H to the associated $C column)

example: Vacation '17 is on 10/15/17  for 5 days because it falls on 10/3/17 & 10/16/17 the data will be copied on the $C and $D columns...    how can I do that??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use these two **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together):

From `cell C2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$11,SMALL(IF((A2<=$F$2:$F$11)*(B2>=$F$2:$F$11)>0,ROW($F$2:$F$11)-ROW($F$1),""),1)),0)
```

From `cell D2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$11,SMALL(IF((A2<=$F$2:$F$11)*(B2>=$F$2:$F$11)>0,ROW($F$2:$F$11)-ROW($F$1),""),1)),"")
```

What these two formulas do is to find the first match and return the value.

Also, I noticed that your `C9 and D12` have different results than mine.  Not sure what is wrong but I am guessing it is due to the sample data you have posted here.  Anyway, try and let me know.

Comment: that's amazing!!!  THANK YOU very much for the help!!
so couple of things:  I noticed the same thing as you but $C is returning a count but it needs to return the value found in $H (my apologies if labels and my explanation are not clear) 
Also the only cells I get results are C8 & C9...   all others are empty...  
-- Looking at the data, I can consolidate the dates that are close to each other - 12/31/2017 -> 1 + 1/1/2018 -> 1 to be one 12/31/2017 -> 2

Comment: I'm unsure but if you add just this portion (A2<=$F$2:$F$11)*(B2>=$F$2:$F$11) to a separate cell, Excel treats this as a 1:1 relationship.  A2 -> F2, A3 - > F3...  because after A12 I see  #VALUE!

Comment: Just noticed that you didn't enter this as an array formula (click `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` altogether) and you should see the curly braces will be included in the formula (see my pic).  Also, those ranges need to be adjusted based on your data input.  I don't recommend to use whole column since it will slow things down but you can do so if you don't have much data in there.

Comment: yeah...  I didn't understand what you meant but I got it working !!  it's awesome...   thank you very much !!  ( the Ctrl+Shit+Enter needs to be pressed on the formula bar to make it an array.... for anyone else that's reading this)

Comment: Correct, and that is how you use an array formula.  It is a powerful feature if you know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C2 and copy across to D2, then copy down:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(H$2:H$4, POWER(SQRT(MAX(IF($F$2:$F$4-$A2>=0, IF($F$2:$F$4-$B2<=0, ROW($F$2:$F$4)-ROW($F$1))))-1), 2)+1), "")`

Answer (score 0):

$C should have the value found in $H and 
$D should have the value found in $G

[image]